# getsockopt SCTP_STATUS error

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

```
getsockopt(sock_fd, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_STATUS, &status, &retsz)
```

returns 'Invalid argument'.
does it means the option SCTP_STATUS is not supported by the system?(Ubuntu12.04)
I'm sure that sock_fd is no problem.
any idea?Thanks in advance

Comment: What is status? What is the value of retsz?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897781/getsockopt-invalid-argument-for-ipproto-sctp-sctp-status). It may help you to solve the problem.